# Реализовать метод, который выведет на экран квадрат максимального значения, которое может содержаться в long. необходимо использовать BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

Вопрос, можно ли реализовать код без импорта константы. В идеи работает, но на портале нет.
Либо может есть другой способ решить ?
Сам код ниже

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long g = MAX_VALUE;
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(g);
    BigInteger summ = b.multiply(b);
    System.out.println(summ);
}
```

}

Comment: Можно. Поглядите значение константы и укажите его явно здесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно не проходит из-за создания переменной с типом Long, а также из-за отсутствия импорта. Попробуй так:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger maxLong = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    BigInteger square = maxLong.multiply(maxLong);
    System.out.println(square);
}
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!!!